# Finding related-node clusters

Tags: graphs

[image]I currently have an undirected weighted graph. I am trying to find a good algorithm for learning/finding a cluster of closely related nodes and/or loosely relationship within a cluster in a graph given a size of the cluster. For example, here the longer edges represent the farther relationship between 2 nodes. We identified 2 clusters where each cluster has a close relationship internally. I am new to computer science, could you please suggest an algorithm or a paper for this problem? Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are trying to solve is called [community detection or community structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure), where several popular algorithms are listed, such as [Girvan–Newman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure#Girvan%E2%80%93Newman_algorithm) and [Minimum-cut method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure#Minimum-cut_method).

You can find many related questions and answers [on this site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Community+detection%22), [on CrossValidate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Community+detection%22) and [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22community+detection%22), such as the following:

- [Community detection in weighted directed graphs for fixed number of communities](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/community-detection-in-weighted-directed-graphs-for-fixed-number-of-communities/59737#59737).
- [How to do community detection in a weighted social network/graph?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/how-to-do-community-detection-in-a-weighted-social-network-graph)
- [What are the differences between community detection algorithms in igraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471906/what-are-the-differences-between-community-detection-algorithms-in-igraph)

A good introduction can be found at [Community detection in graphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0612).

A recent survey can be found at [Community detection in social networks](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/295395520_Community_detection_in_social_networks).